# GPT4All (2.0.0) Unable to instantiate model: code=129, Model format not supported

Tags: llama, gpt4all

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz5zR.png)

**when i use gpt4all==0.2.3 got error below**
(.venv) PS D:\Projects\owngpt> python gpt.py
load INSTRUCTOR_Transformer
max_seq_length  512
loading indexes
loading indexes
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Projects\owngpt\gpt.py", line 29, in 
llm = GPT4All(
File "D:\Projects\owngpt.venv\lib\site-packages\langchain\load\serializable.py", line 97, in **init**
super().**init**(**kwargs)
File "D:\Projects\owngpt.venv\lib\site-packages\pydantic\v1\main.py", line 341, in **init**
raise validation_error
pydantic.v1.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for GPT4All
**root**
GPT4All.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'device' (type=type_error)

**when i use gpt4all==2.0.0 got error below**
(.venv) PS D:\Projects\owngpt> python gpt.py
load INSTRUCTOR_Transformer
max_seq_length  512
loading indexes
gguf_init_from_file: invalid magic number 67676a74
gguf_init_from_file: invalid magic number 67676a74
gguf_init_from_file: invalid magic number 67676a74
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Projects\owngpt\gpt.py", line 23, in 
llm = GPT4All(
File "D:\Projects\owngpt.venv\lib\site-packages\langchain\load\serializable.py", line 97, in **init**
super().**init**(**kwargs)
File "D:\Projects\owngpt.venv\lib\site-packages\pydantic\v1\main.py", line 341, in **init**
raise validation_error
pydantic.v1.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for GPT4All
**root**
Unable to instantiate model: code=129, Model format not supported (no matching implementation found) (type=value_error)

Comment: Did it work with the GGUF model format for `gpt4all v2`? gpt4all.io provides this model: `nous-hermes-llama2-13b.Q4_0.gguf`.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the model format in your code. `gpt4all` wanted the GGUF model format.

Below is the fixed code.

Dependencies:

```bash
pip install langchain faiss-cpu InstructorEmbedding torch sentence_transformers gpt4all
```

Fixed code:

```py
from langchain.document_loaders import WebBaseLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.embeddings.huggingface import HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.llms import GPT4All

from langchain.globals import set_debug

set_debug(True)

# documents = TextLoader("data/text.txt").load()
documents = WebBaseLoader("https://leetcode.com/problem-list/top-interview-questions").load()
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1024, chunk_overlap=64)

texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

instructor_embeddings = HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings(
  model_name="hkunlp/instructor-large",
  model_kwargs={"device": "cpu"}
)

vectorstore = FAISS.from_documents(texts, instructor_embeddings)

question = "Difficulty Problem names"
retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 1})
docs = retriever.get_relevant_documents(question)

print("Loading indices")

llm = GPT4All(
    model="nous-hermes-llama2-13b.Q4_0.gguf",
    max_tokens=2048,
    allow_download=True,
    backend="gptj",
    verbose=True,
)

qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
  llm, retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever()
)

qa_chain(question)
```

Output is incorrect unfortunately.

```
load INSTRUCTOR_Transformer
max_seq_length  512
Loading indices
{'query': 'Difficulty Problem names',
 'result': ' The difficulty of the problem is indicated by a number between 1 and 5, with 1 being the easiest and 5 being the hardest. The problem name corresponds to its LeetCode URL slug, which can be found in the link that appears when you click on the problem title. For example, if you click on "Pick One" from the list of problems above, it will take you to this page: https://leetcode.com/problems/pick-one/. The difficulty level for "Pick One" is 2, which means it\'s a medium problem.'}
```